# Cannot access included file function inside a class

Tags: php, class

When i tried to use this code, i am facing an error.

My Code :

```
require_once 'functions/general.functions.inc';

class AccessingNodes {

    function getNodeId($parent_id){
        $node_id = $this->getNodeIdByParentId($parent_id); // This function is defined in general.functions.inc file
        return $node_id;
    } 

}
```

I can't access a function of that included file. It gives me an error.

Error :

> Fatal Error Call to undefined method
>   AccessingNodes::getNodeIdByParentId

The general.functions.inc is defined by some one. I don't know what is missing here. I got answer for my previous post in SO. In that, it was said that we can treat .inc file's functions as own function of the file. So i called the function using `$this` operator.

Anyone please guide me to overcome this.

Comment: this may be you are using $this

Comment: remove $this-> and then try

Comment: Call only `getNodeIdByParentId($parent_id);` because it's not your class function

Comment: ya. Thanks all. I removed $this and it is working now.

Comment: @EdwinAlex It's not about _making it work_, you should understand why it _works_ and why it did not. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .inc file functions can be treat as own functions of the file but not as own functions of the class.

Remove the $this and the code should work.

Answer (score 2):

You have misunderstanding of `$this`. `$this` is a reference to a calling object. So unless there's a class that extends your class - `AccessingNodes` and has method `getNodeIdByParentId` and your method `getNodeId` is called from the instance of mentioned class in included script, you won't be able to call it. (**Note:** this is awful design, because parent classes should not know anything about child classes)

So take a look what's inside that file.

1. If there's defined only function, use it like a function. E.g.

   ```
   function getParentIdByParentId($id) { }

   class AccessingNodes {

        function getNodeId($parent_id){
             $node_id = getNodeIdByParentId($parent_id); // This function is defined in general.functions.inc file
             return $node_id;
        } 
    }
   ```
2. If it's a static method of some class:

   ```
    class MyClass {
       public static function getNodeIdByParentId($id) {}
    }

    class AccessingNodes {

       function getNodeId($parent_id){
           $node_id = MyClass::getNodeIdByParentId($parent_id); // This function is defined in general.functions.inc file
           return $node_id;
       } 
   }
   ```
3. If there's a class that has method `getNodeIdByParentId` create its instance and call then that method:

   ```
   class MyClass {
       public function getNodeIdByParentId($id) {}
   }

   class AccessingNodes {

       function getNodeId($parent_id){
           $obj = new MyClass;
           $node_id = $obj->getNodeIdByParentId($parent_id); // This function is defined in general.functions.inc file
           return $node_id;
       } 
   }
   ```

p.s. For more information read [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) and take a look at [OOP concepts](https://www.google.com/search?q=OOP+practices&oq=OOP+practices&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l2j62l3.4650&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_rn=2&gs_ri=serp&tok=61gtiZbHWAA_pn064wIpNA&pq=oop%20practices&cp=5&gs_id=4&xhr=t&q=OOP%20concepts&es_nrs=true&pf=p&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&oq=OOP+c&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41867550,d.Yms&fp=dd3b863c0d48009b&biw=1440&bih=775)

Comment: Thanks PLB for driving me clearly. I know oops and i know how to access class functions. In this case, i just get confused by .inc file.. Thanks a lot.